# Can I make my ajax website 'crawlable'?

Tags: ajax, seo, search-engine, google-search, googlebot

I'm currently building a music based website and I want to build something like [this template.](http://radykal.de/themeforest/stylico/) It uses ajax and deep linking. (And it makes use of the History.js library - please notice how there's no '#' in the URLs.)

The reason I want to use these 'ajaxy' methods (or maybe use the template altogether) is so that when music is playing, it will remain un-interrupted as the user navigates the site.

My worry is that my site wont be crawlable by Google but I think I can modify code in the page source to fix that. If I look at the source code to the template, in the head I see

```
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
```

Now if I add this to the head:

```
<meta name="fragment" content="!">
```

will that make the site crawlable? Is there other code I need to add on top of this? Or is it just not possible for this template?

I'm following this guide https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started, and I'm on step 3. I will of course have to complete the other steps but I don't know I'm heading in the right direction, or heading towards a dead end!

Any help would be very much appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From what you said it sounds like your site updates the address bar with clean urls as you navigate via ajax. That's good. The next thing is you want to do is make sure those urls work. If you directly go to a url do you see the specific content it represents. And would a crawler also see the correct content without running javascript. Progressive enhancement works well for that. The final thing is you want to do is make sure bots can pick up those urls.
I've not played with the meta tag for ! But it looks like it is only for the home page and you still need to implement the escaped fragment page. Maybe it does support other pages but the article does not cover that.

Comment: Thank you for you help. I have just noticed that the URL in firefox is clean, but in IE it is ugly! In FF with JS disabled, the 'clean' URL does not show any content except for the navigation bar. Upon clicking any item in the navigation bar, the page loads to show content for that page (but with no styling). I'm a bit confused! Do you think I have a chance of making it crawlable somehow? Many thanks

Comment: Sounds like your code does not work correctly on all browsers. If you want to use progressive enhancement then the clean URL has to show the correct content and then JavaScript makes it cool. Your styling may be failing because you use relative URLs to the css files and your clean URLs are folder based.